# is there a way in java to create xsd schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Is there a way in Java to create an XSD schema? I am trying to create a new schema `.xsd` file according to the number of attributes and their type given to me as input. Is there a package that can help me to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [jlibs](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XMLDocument) library. you can see you to create how to create xml schema using `jlibs.xml.xsd.XSDocument` at the end of the wiki

Comment: did you try this?  the enum types are package protected so the API doesn't work (afaict).

Comment: in java, enums are never package protected. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815592/visibility-of-enum-values-in-java

Answer (score 3):

[JAXB Schemagen](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/twbs_jaxbjava2schema.html) can generate XSD Schema from Java Classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the eclipse's xsd api has the ability to create, parse and update a xsd. [Refer to their documentation](http://eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd) for how-to details.

Answer (score 1):

With [Apache XmlSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/xmlschema20/) you can construct XML schemata in-memory and convert them to string.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I've used the JAXB compiler to generate an object model "home made API" taking the XML schema as XJC input. You can find the file here: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Another solution is to use the Eclipse project MDT XSD (http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd) but I found it not well documented and easily integratable in a Maven build.